# in PMCMD command can we pass source and target tables names

Tags: unix, informatica

need to run a workflow where the session has source and target variables which will be feeded the value through PMCMD command.is it possible

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly pass the source and target table names, but you can parameterize those names and put those in parameter file. Then you can pass the parameter file path in pmcmd.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have source and target names in PMCMD command
Instead create a parameter file and provide the source and target names using the 
parameter identifiers like `$DBConnection_Src=` and `$DBConnection_Tgt=`
Have below format,

```
    [Folder_Naem.WF:Workflow_Name.ST:SessionName]
    $DBConnection_Src=Source_Name
    $DBConnection_Tgt=Target_Name
```

Create this parameter file and provide the path and file name,

[image]
In the mapping tab for source and target provide the parameters specified in the parameter file

[image]

Parameter file is very helpful for dynamic parameter changes. You can edit the parameter file rather than making changes in the informatica workflow